# Instances of Objects in Objective-C - iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I am developing an iOS app that is a calculator to keep track of a score of a certain game. The game has many view controllers. I am going to create a "Player" object and create 4 instances of that player. Now in terms of Objective-C, how would I keep those instances alive between several view controllers? Should I for example, create an array of players and keep passing the array from one VC to another as the view progresses?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using singleton class , you will get the  anywhere the same object. you need not to create each and every time. it create once and you use the app whole.

Comment: Do you know any good Singleton classes tutorials? This looks perfect for the score management class

Answer (score 1):

You can create the 4 instances in AppDelegate.

Then these 4 instances will be accessible by all view controller using shared AppDelegate object.

Let me know in case of any difficulty.

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you Nishant. How would I be able to access them from other classes using the App Delegate? Do I just instantiate an AppDelegate object in each class and then do something along the lines of: appDelegate.object1 ?

Comment: You can create object like below. inside .m file "appDelegate = (<Your Delegate> *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];".....Then in .h file "<Your Delegate> *appDelegate;"

Comment: [((MYApplicationDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick thought, Passing array of Players can resolve your problem. But quickest way to share objects between view controllers is through using Application Delegate as you can simply access application delegate anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

you can use of ApplicationDelegate to store your progress. when you move to another view at that time update your ApplicationDelegate variable in `- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated` method and at another view in viewLoad method get the updated value from the delegate variable.